# Postgres serialization error without serializable transactions

Tags: postgresql

I got this error: ERROR: could not serialize access due to concurrent update

But I'm not using serializable transaction isolation.  Is that possible without setting the default isolation level to serializable?  The postgres docs only mention it for serializable transactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was using psycopg v1 which sets all transactions to serializable by default.  Thanks, RhodiumToad@#postgresql for the hint.